# Alternative to urllib.urlencode for encoding a URL

Tags: python, urlencode, stringio

I'm trying to send a request to an API that only accepts XML. I've used `elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter` to build the XML tree and it's stored in a StringIO object. That's all fine and dandy.

The problem is that I have to urlencode the StringIO object in order to send it to the API. But when I try, I get:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1279, in urlencode
    if len(query) and not isinstance(query[0], tuple):
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

Apparently this has been discussed as [an issue with Python](http://bugs.python.org/issue12327). I'm just wondering if there are any other built-in functions for urlencoding a string, specifically ones that don't need to call `len()` so that I can encode this StringIO object.

Thanks!

**PS:** I'm open to using something other than StringIO for storing the XML object, if that's an easier solution. I just need some sort of "[file](http://effbot.org/zone/xml-writer.htm)" for `SimpleXMLWriter` to store the XML in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringIO` instance is like a file, not like a string. It does not have a `len()`. Use `my_string_io_varaible.getvalue()` to get the string value, and pass it to `urlencode()` which expects a string.

Maybe you could `urlencode` URLs that you embed into the XML along the way, instead of the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a string from your StringIO by calling its getvalue() method, and pass that to urllib.